# git add all .tex files recursively

Tags: git

Cloned a absolutely fresh bare repo.

Now I have a complex file structure with many different files copied in my local working directory. But now I just want to add only all .tex files in all subfolders. But the following doesn't work:

```
git add *.tex #error-message: fatal: pathspec '*.tex' did not match any files
git add /*tex #error-message: fatal: C:/Program Files (x86)/Git/*.tex: 'C:/Program Files(x86)/Git/*.tex' is outside repository
```

Working with git version 1.8.5.2.msysgit.0 on a windows machine.

How to get this working?

### Update

`git add **/*.tex` works well.

Another approach: 
How would it be possible to adjust the .gitignore file, that it ignores everything except .tex files? I tried the following in my .gitignore file and then made a `git add .` but it didnt worked.

```
#Ignore all files
*

#except
!**/*.tex
```

### 2nd Update

Got it working with the following .gitignore file:

```
#Ignore all files
*

#except
!*/
!.gitignore
!*.tex
```

Comment: Have you tried `git add **/*.tex`?

Comment: Have you tried !*.tex in .gitignore?

Comment: @palazzotrain Yes I did. Making an `git add .` results in the message:
fatal: pathspec '.' did not match any files

Answer (score 2):

As you wrote you are on windows, the simplest solution is as follows:

1. start up a powershell
2. cd to the repo root
3. and run this command:

   ls -Include *.tex -Recurse | foreach {git add $_}

I think it is pretty straightforward what this does.

Comment: Thanks, it works well.
But as Platinum Azure wrote, `git add **/*.tex` also works.